# What gets preference when I set an attribute of a textField both from the XML and the code?

Tags: android

Say I set the maxLength of a textField and I do it both from the XML file(say value = 8) and from the code(value = 10). What value gets preference and why?

Comment: It depends on where you set the value from code (onCreate? onResume?). First, the layout is inflated and the XML attributes are applied. Then your onCreate code executes, which can change the values. Then the system performs state restoration, which can potentially override anything you did in onCreate. Then onResume executes.

Comment: So in all the cases, XML gets executed first, right? I thought so but my code is behaving otherwise. FYI, I've put it under onFinishInflate.